# Identify the fluff that I have found in tea

Tags: species-identification, botany, ornithology, hair

I have just opened a new pack of a black Pu'er tea that I've bought at the local store selling it by weight, and found a piece of fluff in there. To me it looks much like some kind of a bird fluff. It might also actually be a plant fluff, but somehow I doubt it. Probably it was white originally, but being so long in contact with the tea made it a bit browner.

Of course it spoiled all the impression of the tea. Now I wonder if I should drink it, or even keep buying at the same store. The worst thing is that their supplier is one of the major suppliers of Chinese tea in our country, and this is not the first time I find something hairy in it. The last time it was a human hair.

The questions:

1. Please help identify what it is (I don't mean a particular species of whatever it is, but at least what is it? Bird fluff, plant fluff, synthetic fluff?)
2. Would you still drink your tea if you'd find such things in it? Like, should it be safe, or is there any risk in contracting some terrible infection or a virus in case if it comes from a bird?

Here are some photos that I've made:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

It also very much looks like this picture I've found in the internet, but failed to find a proper description of what is it actually (the most bold one was that its a swan fluff, but I can't imagine how a swan would come in contact with the tea):

[image]

Comment: It definitely appears to be a down feather. Identifying a specific species would almost certainly require a specialized lab to examine it. I don't think your tea supplier has good quality control.

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of hard to tell from the picture, but maybe it's a variety of [Milkweed seed-pod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asclepias#/media/File:Asclepias_syriaca_seed_pod.jpg) that got into the tea?